What is the strategy for source generated serialization using STJ?
I have a library that I'm trying to migrate from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json. The first phase is basically complete and reflection based serialization works.
But I'd also like to make the library AOT-compatible and that requires the usage of source generation based serialization. According to the documentation I need to inherit JsonSerializationContext and annotate it with JsonSerializable attribute for every type that needs to be serializable.
The problem is that I have maybe a hundred or two hundred types and it would be quite troublesome to do it manually. Is there any other way to achieve this?
[JsonSerializable(typeof(Type1))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(Type2))]
// repeat for every other type
internal partial class MyLibraryContext : JsonSerializerContext;


You only need to apply [JsonSerializable(typeof(TypeN))] for all root types (i.e. ones you pass directly to JsonSerializer.Serialize().  But, as explained in the docs, The types of [root type] members don't need to be explicitly specified with [JsonSerializable] attributes.  ...

... So if all two hundred types might be serialized directly as root objects, then yes it seems you must add them all.  But if only a small percent are ever serialized directly and the remainder are just getting included as part of the serialization graph, then far fewer need be specified.   Does that answer your question?

Yes, maybe a half of the types are accessible from the root type. But there's still the other half that is not accessible from any root type and still each type from it must be annotated separately. It seems there's no other way than to just do that manually
